# HTML Image map not functioning - the image shows up, but no link

Tags: html, wordpress, imagemap

I'm trying to create an image map with a rectangular clickable area in the bottom left area of the image using raw HTML in wordpress.

The image shows up when I use the following code, but no part of the image is clickable.

```
<img class="partners-list" width="1000" height="400" src="/wp-content/uploads/partners.png" alt="Partners" usemap="#partners" />

<map name="partners">
  <area alt="partner1" href="#" coords="126,236,462,350" shape="rect">
</map>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an id to the map tag, like so and it is working on my end:

```
<img class="partners-list" width="1000" height="400" src="/wp-content/uploads/partners.png" alt="Partners" usemap="#partners" />

<map name="partners" id="partners">
  <area alt="partner1" href="http://www.google.com" coords="126,236,462,350" shape="rect">
</map>
```

With the way you have the coords set up, the clickable part of the image is in the left/middle bottom portion of the map.

Comment: I'm trying to get a certain part of the image to be linked. The href is an actual link in the real image, but I didn't want to put the real link in the public post as it's for my company. So there is a link there, just not shown in the codeblock (sorry, should've mentioned that). So I don't know why it's not working

Comment: I updated the code above. It looks like you were missing an id in the map tag.

Comment: Thanks - I actually just realized it's because Wordpress was resizing the image, so my coords were useless. Once I used coords based on the resized display in Wordpress, it worked just fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Really it all boils down to not allowing wordpress to resize your image. So another tip is to use an image that fits inside your page, without being resized.